# Does 兩點九 mean 2:09 or 2:45?

Tags: cantonese, number, time

I heard somebody using 兩點九 and I thought he means 2:09. Actually, by 兩點九 he means 兩點九個字, or 2:45.

Does 兩點九 have two different meanings? Or does it always mean 2:45?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Does 兩點九 have two different meanings? Or does it always mean 2:45?

It does not have two different meanings. It means 2:45.

We can also say 兩點四十五分。 In fact, it's more direct to say 兩點四十五分, if we're looking at a digital clock, since this is what is displayed. With a traditional clock with two hands and 12 numbers each representing a 5-minute period, 兩點九 or 兩點九個字 is more direct.

2:09 is 兩點零九分。

Comment: In old Cantonese, 兩點三個骨 is also 2:45 (三個骨 = 3 quarters)

Comment: Thanks! Then how about 兩點十一？ 2:11 or 2:55?

Comment: 兩點十一 = 2:55; 兩點零十一分 = 2:11

Comment: 2:11 is also 兩點十一分.

Comment: This is must be a mainland China way of telling time, which I've never heard of it.

Comment: @r13 It's Cantonese.

Comment: @monalisa Cantonese only?

Comment: 兩點九 is definitely Cantonese. 二時四十五分 would be the Mandarin way. I suspect only Cantonese would say 兩點半 (2:30) Mandarin would not say 二時半. Cantonese also say 兩點搭九 (2:45)

Comment: @TangHo Mandarin speakers say 兩點半 too.

Comment: Mandarin speakers say also 两点三刻 (兩點三刻).

Answer (score 4):

兩點九 is in **traditional-chinese**,
with the missing characher "分"  ,  implies  Cantonese way of timing.

traditional-chinese is mainly used in HongKong/Taiwan/Macau.

**simplified-chinese** is used in mainland China.

**Cantonese** way of timing is used in HongKong/Macau and southern part of  mainland China.

fuzzy and confusing ,are'nt they? a small table may help.

| time\lang | traditional-chinese(zh-hk) | simplified-chinese(zh-cn) | traditional-chinese(zh-tw) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2:45 | 兩點九[個字] | 两点四十五[分] | not sure |
| Cantonese 2:45 |  | 两点九[个字] | not sure |
| 2:09 | 兩點零九分 | 两点零九[分] | not sure |

letters in () are utf-8 coding reference;

charachers in [] can be omitted.